# What is the equivelant of HttpUtility.UrlEncode in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, character-encoding, urlencode

So far so good... In asp we have the HttpUtility.UrlEncode

Is there any equivelant in vb.net?

I tried importing the system.web without any luck... yet

Comment: Do you have any idea about asp.net? I think you treated asp.net as a language. Isn't it?

Comment: i think i need vacation!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a .NET framework class, not a language feature - so it should work for **any** .NET language*. You just need to add a *reference* to System.Web.dll first.

*=or at least, clients with access to the full framework; so not Silverlight, Compact Framework, Micro Framework or Client Profile